# cakephp group by distinct

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp-2.0

i have a table commande witch contains a date, heure ... i want to return a table witch gives me a commande group by date but my problem i get one commande for each date wwhen i have more than a commande on that date her is my request:

```
$factures = $this->Commande->find('all', array(

                    'conditions' => array(
                        'Commande.prestataire_id' => $this->request->data['prestataire_id']

                    ),
             'group' => array('Commande.date'),
                 'order' => array('Commande.date' => 'DESC'),
                 'fields' => array(' Commande.date'),
                ));
```

here is the output:

```
{
    "status": "Success",
    "status_code": 200,
    "message": "Commande trouvé",
    "data": {
        "everjob_get_Mission": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "Commande": {
                        "date": "2018-04-25"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Commande": {
                        "date": "2018-04-24"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Commande": {
                        "date": "2018-04-23"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Commande": {
                        "date": "2018-04-19"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Commande": {
                        "date": "2018-04-20"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please added sample data with exact output

Comment: i added the output

Comment: currently, what output come from the above query

Answer (score 0):

Try to below code. I hope its work for you not sure.

```
$factures = $this->Commande->find('all', array(
        'fields' => 'DISTINCT Commande.date',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Commande.prestataire_id' => $this->request->data['prestataire_id']

        ),
    'group' => array('Commande.date'),
    'order' => array('Commande.date' => 'DESC')
));
```

Comment: it gives the same output

Comment: Have you wanted each time single records for per date or multiple?